# problem occured during running a django program

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

from django.utils.encoding import force_text
ImportError: cannot import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\LENOVO\OneDrive\Desktop\internet and intranet\django-ecommerce\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)

i am trying to run django program

Answer (score 1):

Django no longer uses `force_text` and is using `force_str`, please look at the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.force_str)